# Python: Function equivalent to chromedriver in firefoxdriver. chromedriver --> firefoxdriver (firefoxdriver gives me syntax error)

Tags: selenium, python-3.8, ubuntu-20.04, selenium-firefoxdriver, firefox-driver

I have this two functions:

```
def get_chromedriver(headless = False):
    import os
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    options = Options()
    options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome'
    options.add_argument('user-data-dir=' + os.environ['HOME'] + '/.config/chromedriver')
    options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation'])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    options.headless = headless
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver', options=options)
    return driver

def get_firefoxdriver(headless = False):
    import os
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
    options = Options()
    options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/firefox'
    options.add_argument('user-data-dir=' + os.environ['HOME'] + '/.config/firefoxdriver')
    options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation'])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    options.headless = headless
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/bin/geckodriver', options=options)
    return driver
```

get_chromedriver function works perfectly but not get_firefoxdriver, which is a copy of the get_chromedriver function.
How can I make the get_firefoxdriver function functionally equivalent to the get_chromedriver function, except for the paths, the webdriver and the browser used?

Comment: You can not switch to chromedrive from firefox in a single execution, I hope that is clear with you.

Comment: Quite the opposite. I copied the function for Chrome, in order to create the function for Firefox. The function for Chrome works perfectly, it is the one for Firefox that does not work.

Comment: yeah it was vice-versa that I did not write, But what is the intention for having both of them in a single project  ?Is it cross browser testing ?

Comment: No, one can choose whether to use Firefox or Chrome for automations, but Chrome is not the goal of this question, I only mentioned it because I took it as a reference to create the function for Firefox.

Comment: @cruisepandey Okay, I've made the question clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox webdriver does not have the same instance methods as the Chrome webdriver. I see that in your Firefox driver creation function you are calling "detach" and "exludeSwitches" options, however if you take a look at the Firefox [documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/firefox_exports_Options.html) you won't find those options whereas the same are available in the Chrome [documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/chrome_exports_Options.html).

There are pros and cons in using each driver, and as in every case the solution should match the use case.

Comment: This documentation does not explain how to detach the firefox browser from the terminal

Comment: Precisely my point, "detach" is not a supported option in Firefox webdriver.

Comment: Except that the documentation doesn't list all the arguments available for each method but only the methods, so I don't know if among the arguments available for each method, there is something that suits me.